# JSValueがもつプロパティ名の一覧を取得したい

Tags: ios, c#, xamarin

Xamarin.iOSのJavaScriptCoreに関する質問です。

JSValueインスタンスのもつプロパティ名の一覧を取得したいです。

以下のJSを`JSContext`に読み込ませたとします。

```js
var test = {
  a: 1,
  b: "bです",
  c: [12, 13, 14]
}
```

ここから`test`オブジェクトを取得することはできます。
`JSValue test = context[(NSString)"test"]`

問題はここからで`test`オブジェクトのプロパティが動的でどんな名前かわからない時、そのプロパティを名前と値のペアで取得したいです。

名前が分かれば`JSValue.GetProperty(string key)`で値を取得できるので名前だけでも分かれば良いです。

重要なのは**名前と値のペア**なので`JSValue.GetValueAt(nuint index)`は使えません。

何か方法があれば教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`test`に与えられた値が、ご質問に記載されたようなもの(JavaScriptのobject)であれば、`ToDictionary()`メソッドで辞書型に変換してしまえば良いのではないでしょうか?

```
        if (test.IsObject)
        {
            var dict = test.ToDictionary();
            var keys = dict.Keys;
            foreach( var key in keys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(key+":"+dict[key]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("`test` is not an object");
        }
```

`dict`は`NSDictionary`型になるので、その他の[`NSDictionary`型](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/foundation.nsdictionary?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12)のメソッドを使うことも出来ます。

Comment: `ToDictionary`は試したんですがうまく動かなかったんですよね。ですが提示していただいたコードで簡単に動きました。ありがとうございます！！